# How to get real file path from a BLOB

Tags: sql-server, remote-blob-storage

I have a situation in which data (mostly images) is stored in a BLOB.  As you know data in BLOB are guid like which I cannot relate to any file.  My question is, is there a way by which I can extract the real path, file name etc of that particular BLOB.  The idea behind this question is to create an extra table in which I will list the blob values and associate with them the file name etc... 
EXAMPLE:

```
BLOB Value1| ASCII Value1|BLOB Value2| ASCII Value2|BLOB Value3|ASCII Value3
1123123    |  C:\        | 324234    | picture     |345345453  | .jpg
```

Please note I am a newbie in this area just finished installing my first BLOB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the purpose behind the table?  Accessing the BLOB data directly outside of the SP API is not supported.

That being said, MS has a sample RBS implementation and details how it works which may help you out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc905212(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer, basically i need to create an xml file with data of blob and real data,  basically imagine the table above in xml.

Comment: @IanCian As @JesusShelby has said, accessing BLOB data directly outside of the API is not supported.

Comment: Hi there can you please help me and give me some examples, useful links for me to understand this API in order to be able to get the content in a database + blob information

Comment: Example: I want to make a C# application which reads information from the content_database of sharepoint and read the blob data as well in order to display it outside of sharepoint

Comment: I don't think you will find any specific examples.  Here are more examples of the RBS provider:  http://sqlrbs.codeplex.com/

Comment: 10x for the reply, but still cannot find a way to get the physical path of where the file is being stored :(.  I know that the file is stored in _C:\Sharepoint\Blobstore\5f42b96e-a589-44d8-9b63-8e064a9a6ae6\d86424b3-cbc6-4184-afb8-8088be3fbbbf_ because checked it out manually.  All I wanted is to get this path through code or sql.  Aparently this is a real hard task.